# Connect Tableau to Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I tried to connect Tableau to Hortonworks sandbox with all the possibilities.
What am I doing wrong?

```
server :192.168.56.101 
Port:10000
Type : Hive2
Username : sandbox
```

Also I have given grant select on table in hue. Still it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you use username root and password hadoop and try ? Does that work for you?

I use Aqua Data Studio to connect to the Hortonworks sandbox and the one issue I found with Hortonworks 2.2 and username authentication was I needed to add the parameter 
?auth=noSasl to the url. Can you try this and let me know of this works for you? Please attach the error message you are getting ..
[image]
[image]